# Having difficulty when trying to return to previous JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am having difficulty when trying to return to previous `JFrame`. In FirstFrame, it has a parameter. In secondFrame, how can I back to firstFrame since it does not has parameter ?

I am pulling my hair out of this. Any help would be appreciated.

**FirstFrame.java**

```
public class FirstFrame extends JFrame
{
public FirstFrame(final String name)
{
 goToSecondFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
              {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                SecondFrame sec= new SecondFrame();
                sec.createAndShowGui();
               sec.setVisible(true);
               setVisible(false);
               dispose();       
            }
              });
}
}
```

**SecondFrame.java**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                createAndShowGui();
            });
        }

     static void createAndShowGui() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Second Frame");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(new Second());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

public Second()
{
 back.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                  {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                  FirstFrame back = new FirstFrame(); // Getting error
                  back.setVisible(true);
                  setVisible(false);
                  dispose();         

                }
                  });
}
```

Comment: What is `button frame = new button();` ?

Comment: @SureshKoya I have edited my post

Comment: *back*.addActionListener(new ActionListener() and FirstFrame *back* why are you using the same name?

Comment: @vsambor I implemented it wrongly?

Comment: @Tony I just can't understand if it's ok how you're doing... calling *back* addActionListener before initializing the back Frame. So before this : * FirstFrame back = new FirstFrame(); // Getting error* you are calling this: *back.addActionListener(new ActionListener()* is that ok?

Comment: @vsambor When back button pressed, it will back to FirstFrame, But I have no idea how to achieve this ><

Comment: can you post all the classes code? I want to test it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110768/discussion-between-tony-and-v-sambor).

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your frame first in the top of the class:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Delete Admin");
```

and then do like this:

```
back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{ 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{ 
staffManagment back = new staffManagment(""); 
back.setVisible(true); 
setVisible(false); 
frame.dispose(); 
} 
});
```